# Is there anyway to force loader to load shared library at a fixed address?

Tags: linker, loader

I have an own shared library which is doing something low level. It needs to know it's loaded start address at compile time.

Is there anyway to force loader to load a shared library at a fixed address?

Answer (score 2):

```
# create linker script

$ export BASE_ADDRESS=0x00800000
$ gcc -shared -Wl,--verbose 2>&1 | sed -e '/^======/,/^======/!d' -e '/^======/d;s/0\(.*\)\(+ SIZEOF_HEADERS\)/'$BASE_ADDRESS'\1\2/' >foo.lds

# build and link with linker-script

$ gcc -shared foo.c -o foo.o
$ gcc -Wl,-T,foo.lds -shared -fPIC foo.o -o foo.so
$ objdump --syms foo.so 

foo.so:     file format elf32-i386

SYMBOL TABLE:

00800114 l    d  .note.gnu.build-id 00000000              .note.gnu.build-id
00800138 l    d  .gnu.hash  00000000              .gnu.hash
0080016c l    d  .dynsym    00000000              .dynsym
008001fc l    d  .dynstr    00000000              .dynstr
...
```