# C++ placement new and inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, memory-management

## Background:

- I am using C++ 20
- I am using shmget/shmat to create a big chunck of shared memory. Inside this shared memory, I initialize a dlmalloc instance, allowing multiple processes to allocate and deallocate together within the shared memory.
  I have also created allocators to facilitate use of standard C++ containers within my shared memory. For example:

```
template <typename T>
class SimMemoryAllocator
{
    public:
        typedef size_t size_type;
        typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
        typedef T* pointer;
        typedef const T* const_pointer;
        typedef T& reference;
        typedef const T& const_reference;
        typedef T value_type;

        constexpr SimMemoryAllocator() noexcept = default;
        constexpr SimMemoryAllocator(const SimMemoryAllocator&) noexcept = default;
        template <class U>
        constexpr SimMemoryAllocator(const SimMemoryAllocator<U>&) noexcept {}

        constexpr bool operator==(const SimMemoryAllocator& rhs) noexcept {return true;}
        template <class U>
        constexpr bool operator==(const SimMemoryAllocator<U>& rhs) noexcept {return true;}

        T* allocate(size_type num, const void* hint = nullptr)
        {
            T* t = (T*)SharedMemoryCAlloc(sim_memory, num, sizeof(T));
            return t;
        }

        void deallocate(pointer ptr, size_type num)
        {
            if (ptr)
            {
                SharedMemoryFree(sim_memory, ptr);
            }
        }
};

typedef std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, SimMemoryAllocator<char>> SimString;
template <typename T>
using SimVector = std::vector<T, SimMemoryAllocator<T>>;
template <typename T>
using SimSet = std::set<T, std::less<T>, SimMemoryAllocator<T>>;
```

- This is used within a dynamic binary instrumentation context, which complicates things and makes debugging and profiling quite hard to do, if not impossible, with existing tools.

## Usage:

I have some objects that I want to allocate within the shared memory described above. This should be simple, where I allocate memory through my dlmalloc, then use placement new to construct the objects in place. This works for most things, except (I think) for the case of inherited objects.

Consider the following:

- I have the following base class, which is comprised of POD types, as well as some of my shared memory containers:

```
class Timing
{
    UTILS::COMM::SimString name;

    uint64_t min_start_cycle;
    uint64_t first_try_cycle;
    uint64_t simulation_cycle;
    uint64_t delay;
    uint16_t priority;

    // Part of a graph
    UTILS::COMM::SimSet<Timing*> parents;
    UTILS::COMM::SimVector<Timing*> children;

    static std::atomic<
            uint64_t> active_event_count;

    static STATS::CounterStat* event_count_stat;
    static STATS::CounterStat* event_cycles_stat;

    // Includes many virtual member functions. Not shown for brevity
}
```

As far as I understand, if I allocate and construct the above through my shared memory and placement new, the object itself will be placed in the shared memory (including the PODs, the atomic, as well as the "headers" of the containers). The bodies of the containers will also be allocated in my shared memory, since they use my custom allocator above.

- I have other classes inheriting from the above base class, all of which strictly add POD types. Example:

```
class CacheEvent : public EVENT::Timing
{
    Base* cache;
    uint16_t thread;
    uint64_t address;
    uint32_t bank;
    uint32_t index;
}
```

Again, my understanding is that if I allocate and construct a derived object like the above through my shared memory allocation and placement new, then it will be entirely placed in my shared memory.

- Here is how I generally create my events:

```
// Helpers
template <TimingEvent T, typename... V>
T* CreateEvent(V&&... args)
{
    void* mem = UTILS::COMM::SharedMemoryAlloc(UTILS::COMM::sim_memory, sizeof(T));
    return new(mem) T(std::forward<V>(args)...);
}

template <TimingEvent T>
void DeleteEvent(T* event)
{
    event->~T();
    UTILS::COMM::SharedMemoryFree(UTILS::COMM::sim_memory, event);
}

// Example usage of helpers:
EVENT::Timing* miss_event = EVENT::CreateEvent<MissEvent>(params, to, object, constructor);
```

## Problem:

There are no issues with the classes/objects described above, or their member containers. I have not encountered data corruptions or segfaults, though I am yet to use them in multiple processes, only one for now. However, I have noticed that my memory usage (not the shared memory portion) increases a lot as my app progresses (I am creating many thousands of these objects during my app's lifetime). It would jump up by about 1GB within 1 minute.

I have enabled/disabled various parts of my app until I made sure that creating the objects above is the cause of this increased memory usage (as mentioned above, I cannot use memory profiling directly, so had to do this the old fashioned way). This was baffling since I made sure everything is allocated within my shared memory. Then I came across [this article](https://www.vishalchovatiya.com/memory-layout-of-cpp-object/) while googling.

Based on this article, I am now thinking that the type_info and vtables of my objects are the culprit. So, while the objects get created in my shared memory, their type_infos and vtables would be in the heap? If true, this is problematic for two reasons:

1. It would prevent multi process use, since only the creating process would have the type_info and vtable.
2. I want to limit memory usage outside my shared memory, which this quickly eats up.

So, am I correct to accuse the type info and vtables? Is there another candidate? The natural second question is whether there are workarounds?

Comment: Side note: You only need to declare `value_type`, `allocate` and `deallocate` in your allocator type. The rest is redundantly already provided by `allocator_traits` defaults.

Comment: You show how you use `CreateEvent`, but not `DeleteEvent`. Do you make sure that you call `DeleteEvent` with the same type `T` as `CreateEvent` was originally called, rather than passing a base class pointer? Because otherwise your leak/UB is right there in the `SharedMemoryFree` call.

Comment: And another side note: Both functions are also not exception-safe. If the constructor or destructor throws, you leak memory as well.

Comment: Also, that you are storing `Timing*` in the vectors is suspicious. Are the vectors supposed to be non-owning? Do you make sure that you delete the objects referred to by these vectors?

Comment: All in all, I think this needs a [mre].

Comment: And one more: Do you make sure to map the shared memory to the same address in all processes? If not, then you can't use native pointers like your `SimMemoryAllocator` does.

Comment: - I do map the shared memory to the same address in all processes. Been using this setup for a while and it works well for other non-inheritance related things.

- I free everything through the base class pointer, not the same type it was created with. However, my base class destructor is virtual.

-  The events I use above are part of a graph, they only point to parents and children but don't own them. As I traverse through the graph I delete parent nodes and create a wavefron of children nodes to keep traversing.

Comment: I will try an MRE next, will post it here as an edit.

Comment: "_However, my base class destructor is virtual._": That's irrelevant. The virtual destructor makes sure that `event->~T();` behaves as expected to destroy the object, but the `event` pointer is still pointing at the beginning of the base class subobject, not the complete object for which you allocated the memory. So you are deallocating an offset pointer, which your allocator very likely doesn't support. This can be solved by using a virtual function that calls `SharedMemoryFree` on the most-derived type, which is how compilers implement `delete basePtr;` (so-called "deleting destructor")

Comment: I understand your point. But doesn't the base and its enclosing derived object start at the same address? dlmalloc needs only the address to delete, it knows the size of the allocated chunk internally. So, whether I call the DeleteEvent on a base pointer or a derived pointer it should not matter.

Comment: "_But doesn't the base and its enclosing derived object start at the same address?_": No, this is only guaranteed for standard-layout classes. Especially if you have virtual functions, it is unlikely to be true.

Comment: I don't understand how this can be true, while at the same time one can cast a derived object pointer back to its base object pointer and use it safely. If they don't always start at the same address then such casting should not be allowed?!

Comment: The compiler knows the layout of the class (the offset is fixed at compile-time) and will compile a `static_cast` or implicit conversion so that it adds the necessary offset. A `reinterpret_cast` would indeed not work and lead to undefined behavior because it ignores the offset.

Comment: You're correct that vtables probably won't work cross process but they're not the source of your memory leak as there'll generally only be a single vtable for all instances of a class https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667063/do-all-instances-of-the-same-c-class-share-a-vtable-or-would-each-one-get-its

Comment: Right, the vtables need to be at the same address in each process as well. That's going to be difficult to achieve especially if ASLR is used.

Comment: type_info and vtables are one per class, and are allocated statically. They are not your problem.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Can't you just use **boost.interprocess**? They have already done what you are trying to do: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/interprocess/quick_guide.html

Comment: If all your processes are identical (i.e. all `fork` 'd from the same parent and no `exec` 'd), your system can work. Otherwise you need to make sure your classes reside in shared libraries, and all relevant shared libraries are mapped to the same address in all processes. This will attempt to locate vtables and type info at the same address in each process. Even then there's no guarantee, but at least there's some chance to work.

Comment: I just tried to do a simple proof-of concept and it worked for me, provided that the relevant vtables are never emitted in the executables but only in the shared library. (It's easy if the executable only sees abstract classes, and no concrete children; the latter should be encapsulated in the shared library). I used a linker script similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18762624/775806) but fixed all 4 main sections (text, data, rodata and bss), just in case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for polymorphic classes (i.e. classes with `virtual` functions) to work in shared memory, you need to assure that the vtables and type_info objects are located at the same address in each process, because the vptr in the polymorphic objects always is a raw native pointer and that can't be changed.

This should be possible to achieve if the processes are `fork`ed from one another (without any `exec`), after any relevant dynamic libraries containing the necessary vtables and type_infos have been loaded. The `fork` will not change the address of anything already mapped in either parent or child.

However, if you start the processes any other way, including any `exec` after `fork`, it will be difficult to make this guarantee. Operating systems typically use ASLR and will map the executable and library segments at different addresses for each process. Even if you disable this, you'll probably still have other similar issues.

---

In the comments you say that you guarantee the shared memory to be mapped at the same address in each process. (If that was not guaranteed then the use of raw native pointers in the custom allocator would be wrong as well.)

If you do not use the `fork` approach, you will have similar issues to achieve this. `shmat` allows specifying an address, but you are then relying on this address region not already being in use e.g. because ASLR chose it for a shared library.

---

However, if the vtable wasn't located at the correct address, your program would fail much more violently than just leaking memory, if you actually create the object in one process and try to call a virtual function on it in another.

The bug causing just the memory leak is much more simple and has nothing to do with shared memory.

According to the comments you are calling `DeleteEvent` on a base class pointer of the allocated object.

If the destructor is `virtual` then `event->~T();` is ok and will correctly destroy the most-derived object.

However `event` in `DeleteEvent` is still a pointer at the base class subobject. The address represented by that pointer is in general not equal to the address represented by a pointer to the most-derived object which you placed at the start of the allocated memory. This means that the address you are passing to `SharedMemoryFree` is generally not the address returned by `SharedMemoryAlloc`, but may instead point somewhere else in the allocated region. Allocators generally do not support that.

Only for standard-layout classes (which never can have `virtual` functions) is it guaranteed that base class subobjects are located at the same address as the derived object. For the layout of other classes you have to look at the relevant ABI specification, i.e. probably the [Itanium C++ ABI](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#class-types) in your case.

You must call `DeleteEvent` on a pointer to the most-derived object. The way compilers achieve this to make `delete basePtr;` work, is by emitting an additional destructor per class with `virtual` destructor, called the "*deleting destructor*" that behaves like a `virtual` function and calls the deallocation function with the most-derived type after destructing the object. That approach can also work manually.

---

Of course, nothing so far considers synchronization of the shared memory, which is a completely separate topic.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do use exec, not just fork. I map the shared memory to the same address on all processes by hacking into a memory range that is **almsot** never used in practice.

It seems if I want to keep polymorphic objects in shared memory I have to go with the shared lib solution mentioned in the comments. For now, I am fixing the bug you described. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @mewais Either way, this seems like a bit of a dangerous hack. I would reconsider whether the polymorphic classes are really required or a `std::variant` of the derived types wouldn't work as well.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create objects in shared memory which have virtual functions.  You're asking about memory leaks, but that doesn't matter because the overall design can't work.  If you create in shared memory an instance of a class which has a vtable pointer, that pointer will only be correct for that one process.  This is just a special case of the general rule that objects placed in shared memory must not contain pointers (e.g. you can't put a std::vector in shared memory and have it work across processes--see Boost Interprocess).

Comment: Actually, with boost.interprocess you can put STL containers and strings on shared memory. The only limitation is polymorphic types, due to ABI problems.

Comment: As long as you assure that the vtables are mapped at the same address in each process, why shouldn't virtual functions work? Also, OP says that they guarantee that the shared memory is mapped at the same address in each process, so why wouldn't native pointers stored in the shared memory work as long as they only refer to memory in the same shared memory segment? `std::vector` should then work just fine with a custom allocator. Even if they are not mapped at the same address, `std::vector` with a custom allocator that uses e.g. an `offset_ptr` as `pointer` type should work fine.

Comment: @user17732522 there is no portable way to assure that. In different porcess vtable of same class may have a different address - possibly in may work with `fork()` on some implementations, when process is a same program and `fork()` was called after creation.

Comment: I have used vectors, strings, sets, maps, in my shared memory using custom allocators for about a year now with no issue. I have been creating objects there as well. All of these work fine. The only issue I have is with base/derived objects.